# reshape - prevent categorical variable from repeating over columns

Tags: r, reshape

I want to change a table from long to wide. It has multiple values and a  categorical variables.

table looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("john", "mary", "john", "mary"), 
variable = c("math", "math", "science", "science"), 
grade = c("sixth", "sixth", "sixth", "sixth"), 
val1 = c(78, 88, 97, 100), val2 = c(92, 83, 69, 94))
```

What I want is this:

```
want <- data.frame(name = c("john", "mary"), grade = c("sixth", "sixth"),
math.val1 = c(78, 88), math.val2 = c(92, 83), science.val1 = c(97, 100), 
science.val2 = c(69, 94))
```

Without the grade column, I am able to achieve this easily:

```
reshape(df, idvar='name', timevar='variable', direction='wide')
```

With the "grade" column, I get :

```
  name grade.math val1.math val2.math grade.science val1.science val2.science
1 john      sixth        78        92         sixth           97           69
2 mary      sixth        88        83         sixth          100           94
```

How can I correct this?

Thanks.

Comment: In R the term "aggregate" means you are collapsing data with grouping criterai with a summary measure such as `mean` or `sd`. This instance is not well described as "aggregation".

Comment: right. i've corrected it.

Comment: honestly, this wasn't a good question - should I close / delete it? Is that the right thing to do?

Comment: Too late now. Questions with upvoted answers cannot be deleted... and I didn't think it was a bad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include 'grade' into idvar.

```
reshape(df, idvar=c('name', 'grade'), timevar='variable', direction='wide')
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `devel` version of `data.table` i.e. `v1.9.5`, reshaping multiple value columns is possible with `dcast`.  It can be installed from [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), name+grade~variable, value.var=c('val1', 'val2'))
#   name grade math_val1 science_val1 math_val2 science_val2
#1: john sixth        78           97        92           69
#2: mary sixth        88          100        83           94
```

Comment: I tried this reading in the other similar question . Could not install from github due to admin restrictions. Is this being updated in r-cran soon ?

Comment: @vagabond I don't know when it will be updated.  This `dcast` approach is very new.